# SlideUp/SlideDown dropdown value

Tags: javascript, slidedown, slideup

I would like some assistance with JavaScript.
I have the following dropdown:

[image]

All the fields in the drop down are hard coded values with set ID fields, I would like to know if it would be possible to hide the following row if it is empty?

[image]

Depending on the selecting in the dropdown the Name and Customs Code fields gets populated with information from the database, certain selections leaves the name and custom code fields empty. Is there a way where I could hide these fields by using the SlideUp() or SlideDown() method?

I am quite new to JavaScript so any advise will be much appreciated

Comment: Can you post the code that has these dropdowns?

Comment: This website is all about code. Please make [mre] and use `<>` button in your editor to make snippet. Pictures don't help here.